# IronAHK error not working with AutoHotKey script

Tags: macos, mono, autohotkey

Okay so I have recently migrated to a MacBook Pro from my windows computer where I have many AutoHotKey scrips to control my work flow and many applications especially when graphic designing, I have spend hours upon hours on these scripts and didn't want to lose them. So I found out about IronAHK installed mono, xquartz and the monoide. 
Upon installing and running ironAHK the example script the hello world box works fine however when using a more complicated script this error occurs.

```
XXX-MacBook-Pro-2:~ XXXX $ ironahk /Users/XXXX/Desktop/haxs2/cs.ahk 
WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
Using default runtime: v4.0.30319

Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: libX11.dylib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) IronAHK.Rusty.Linux.X11.Xlib:XOpenDisplay (intptr)
  at IronAHK.Rusty.Linux.XConnectionSingleton.Listen () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: libX11.dylib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) IronAHK.Rusty.Linux.X11.Xlib:XOpenDisplay (intptr)
  at IronAHK.Rusty.Linux.XConnectionSingleton.Listen () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

So I've got no idea what this error is could someone please tell me how to fix it. I have tried reinstalling changing locations using the CD command nothing is working. Could someone please help :) 
Or even provide another application which will be able to run my AHK scripts :). Thank you!! :)

I opened the binary in Xamarin Studio and there are 9 fatal errors and one warning all regarding 'using NUnit.Framework;'
Could someone please tell me how to fix so I can compile the binary and hopefully this will work. Thank you :)

Comment: IronAHK was never finished. It's abandon-ware. No one is actively developing it. You have two options for AHK on Mac, run an Emulated version of Windows use it to run AHK through that or try rewriting your scripts in Applescript or Python scripting languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just letting everyone know the answer, if you download wine bottler and go to pre ported application AutoHotKey is actually already and option so you can download that and it works perfectly! :) 
So there is no need to use ironAHK :)